# Correct pattern to call a service containing an async call from an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to TAP and async/await in practice in **C#** so I may have some bad code smells here, so be gentle. :-)

I have a service method that looks as follows:

```
public OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListOutput AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToList(
    OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListInput aParams)
{
    var result = new OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListOutput();
    try
    {
        var mailChimManager = new MailChimpManager(aParams.MailChimpApiKey);
        Task<Member> mailChimpResult =
            mailChimManager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(
                aParams.Listid, 
                new Member                                                                                                     
                {
                    EmailAddress = aParams.EmailAddress
                });

        //Poll async task until it completes. 
        //Give it at most 8 seconds to do what it needs to do
        var outOfTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8);
        while (!mailChimpResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now > outOfTime)
            {
                throw new Exception("Timed out waiting for MailChimp API.");
            }
        }

        //Should there have been a problem with the call then we raise an exception
        if (mailChimpResult.IsFaulted)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                mailChimpResult.Exception?.Message ?? 
                "Unknown mail chimp library error.", 
                mailChimpResult.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            //Call to api returned without failing but unless we have 
            //the email address subscribed we have an issue
            if (mailChimpResult.Result.Status != Status.Subscribed)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"There was a problem subscribing the email address
                    {aParams.EmailAddress} to the mailchimp list id 
                    {aParams.Listid}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.ResultErrors.AddFatalError(PlatformErrors.UNKNOWN, ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But when I call in from **MVC Controller** action `mailChimpResult.IsCompleted` always returns `false` and eventually I hit the timeout.

I realise this is because I am not chaining the async calls as per [HttpClient IsComplete always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540237/httpclient-iscomplete-always-return-false) and because of different threads this behaviour is "expected".

However I want my service method to hide the complexity of the `async` nature of what it is doing and merely do what appears to be a synchronous call in my action method namely:

```
 var mailChimpResult =
    _PlatformMailChimpService.AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToList(
        new OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListInput                                                                                                                                            
        {
            EmailAddress = aFormCollection["aEmailAddress"],                                                                                                                                           
            Listid = ApplicationSettings.Newsletter.MailChimpListId.Value,                                                                                                                                          
            MailChimpApiKey = ApplicationSettings.Newsletter.MailChimpApiKey.Value
        });

 if (mailChimpResult.Result == true)
 {
    //So something
 }
```

Comment: You need to do `async` all the way. "Hiding" it will always lead to painful discoveries - usually [deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock). There is essentially no way around it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but as my service call returns no async handle etc. how am I supposed to implement this. Can you give me an example based on my code?

Comment: It is in the service call that you are hiding it. You need to `await` the call to `AddOrUpdateAsync`, rather than polling it - that is the big code smell. Then you can make the service method async and await that in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should avoid the `.Result` and `.IsFaulted` properties of the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects, that was code smell number one. When you're using these objects you should use `async` and `await` through the entire stack. Consider your service written this way instead:

```
public async Task<OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListOutput> 
    AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToList(
        OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListInput aParams)
{
    var result = new OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListOutput();
    try
    {
        var mailChimManager = new MailChimpManager(aParams.MailChimpApiKey);
        Member mailChimpResult =
            await mailChimManager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(
                aParams.Listid, 
                new Member                                                                                                     
                {
                    EmailAddress = aParams.EmailAddress
                });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.ResultErrors.AddFatalError(PlatformErrors.UNKNOWN, ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice that I was able to remove all of that unnecessary polling and examining of properties. We mark the method as `Task<OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListOutput>` returning and decorate it with the `async` keyword. This allows us to use the `await` keyword in the method body. We `await` the `.AddOrUpdateAsync` which yields the `Member`.

The consuming call into the service looks similar, following the same paradigm of `async` and `await` keywords with `Task` or `Task<T>` return types:

```
var mailChimpResult =
    await _PlatformMailChimpService.AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToList(
        new OzCpAddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListInput                                                                                                                                            
        {
            EmailAddress = aFormCollection["aEmailAddress"],                                                                                                                                           
            Listid = ApplicationSettings.Newsletter.MailChimpListId.Value,                                                                                                                                          
            MailChimpApiKey = ApplicationSettings.Newsletter.MailChimpApiKey.Value
        });

 if (mailChimpResult.Result == true)
 {
    //So something
 }
```

It is considered best practice to postfix the "Async" word to the method, to signify that it is asynchronous, i.e.; `AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToListAsync`.

Comment: And the controller method then just becomes `var mailChimpResult = await _PlatformMailChimpService.AddOrUpdateEmailAddressToList(...); if (mailChimpResult.Result == true){}` so still hiding the complexity, apart from the addition of one word

Comment: @David thanks for that. I had refactored before I saw your reply. Only further addition was to make the controller action async as well.